# Android SQLite like query with multiple, optional conditions as a prepared statement

Tags: java, android, sqlite, select

I'm quite new to Android, and I'm trying to query a database table "Houses" with the columns size, owner and city.

I am trying to implement a method

```
getHousesFromDatabase(String owner, String city, Integer size)
```

where *city* and *size* can be null. The method is supposed to return all the rows where the *size, location, city* fields match the parameters, but only if the parameter is not null.
i.e.

`getHousesFromDatabase("John", null, null);` should return all the rows where the owner is John, regardless of the other columns.

`getHousesFromDatabase("John", "San Francisco", null);` should return all the rows where the owner is John and that are in San Francisco, and so on.

My current implementation goes like this

```
   public House getHousesFromDatabase(String owner, String city, Integer size) {
        if (city == null && size == null) {
            Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select * from " + SQLiteHelper.TABLE_HOUSES + " where "
                    + COLUMN_OWNER + " like '" + owner + "%" + "'", null);
        }
        else if (city == null) {
            Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_HOUSES + " where "
                    + COLUMN_OWNER + " like '" + owner + "%" + "'" +" and where " + COLUMN_SIZE + "like '"+ size +"%'", null);
        }
        else if (size == null) {
            ...
        }
        else {
           ...
        }
    }
```

where the if statements cover each possible variation; But this feels horribly clumsy to me, and I wonder if there is a simpler way, and one that results in a prepared statement? (from what I read, `rawQuery()` alone is vulnerable to SQL injections, and `SQLiteStatement.execute()` is not to be used for queries).

Comment: What do you mean with "vulnerable"? And why don't you simply construct the SQL string dynamically?

Comment: vulnerable to SQL injections, I thought (I'll update the question). And I thought that using something like the SQLiteDatabase.query() method automatically prevents SQL injections, whereas the  SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery() method doesn't. So you would suggest dynamic construction of the rawQuery() String? 
I wondered if it was possible to do this more dynamically with query(), or to use a dynamic rawQuery() with protection against SQL Injections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `rawQuery()` and `query()` are vulnerable to SQL injections in exactly the same way, but only if you insert string values directly into the SQL string without using parameters.

You should just construct the SQL statement dynamically:

```java
Cursor getHousesFromDatabase(String owner, String city, Integer size) {
    String[] params = new String[(owner != null ? 1 : 0) +
                                 (city  != null ? 1 : 0) +
                                 (size  != null ? 1 : 0)];
    int paramIndex = 0;
    String where = "";
    if (owner != null) {
        where = COLUMN_OWNER + " LIKE ?";
        params[paramIndex++] = owner + "%";
    }
    if (city != null) {
        if (!where.equals(""))
            where = where + " AND ";
        where = where + COLUMN_CITY + " LIKE ?";
        params[paramIndex++] = city + "%";
    }
    if (size != null) {
        if (!where.equals(""))
            where = where + " AND ";
        where = where + COLUMN_SIZE + " LIKE ?";
        params[paramIndex++] = size + "%";
    }
    return db.query(TABLE_HOUSES, columns, where, params, null, null, null);
}
```